# HTML Dynamically change date to either Mon, Wed or Fri

Tags: javascript, php, html

Need to dynamically update a future date shown on a page based on current date.

EX) we offer a presentation on mon, wed & fri at 8pm EST
if someone visits the page on tue, need the date to reflect the wed day+date ... if they visit on thurs, need date of the next presentation to reflect fri day name+date

Tues or Weds visit would see: Wed, January 6
Thurs or Fri visit would see: Fri, January 8
Sat, Sun or Mon visit would see: Monday January 10

here's what i've got so far, but I'm at an impasse on how to get the M,W or F to populate based on current date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var months=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];       
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24));       
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
</script>
```

Comment: use the `DateTime` ( and associated ) class - perfect for this type of thing.

Comment: Do you have any example code to show? or are you just trying to get someone to do the work for free?

Comment: @ChrisDaigle you could simply add number of days to add to date object it will the work for you. refer my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... I think I have the direction i need to crack the code!

Comment: @ChrisDaigle great it worked out. please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to get the current date, check what day it is, and then display the correct future date based on the day.

You'll want to start by getting the current date:

```
 var date = new Date();
```

From there, you can get the day, with [date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

You can then set a future date with [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

I would spend some time looking through MDN's documentation on the Date object, you'll find that there are a number of methods you can use to accomplish what you're going after. You might find [is.js](https://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/) and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) helpful as well, if you don't want to get "low-level".

You'll learn more if you give this a try yourself. Simply getting the code written for you on SO won't be as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> //You didn't mention on which language you working on, you use
>   javascript and PHP tags, in your question, so i am going to give you
>   answer in php language...

I am sorry chris daigle, 
I am very tired, i cant write big code, but i give you some idea, to work on,,, you can get next coming moday/friday date using

```
strtotime( "next monday" );
```

e.g:

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime( "next monday" ) );
//this will print coming Monday date
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime( "next friday" ) );
```

**Now come on solution**

Get Today Day

```
$today_day = date("l"); //l => small L
```

Now check if today sat/sunday

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime( "next monday" ) );
```

Hope you understand....

Answer (score 0):

**Simple JS Solution:**

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); //Adds 1 day to current date you could try changing value and see how it works


var months = ["January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

var days = ["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat"];

document.getElementById("disDate").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()] + ", " + months[ d.getMonth() ] + " " + d.getDate();
</script>
```

Add div with `disDate` id on html.

Refer to documentation on Date() in JS for better understanding.